# How do I duplicate fragments?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, duplicates, fragment

My FragmentActivity loops and creates 8 Fragments from the same xml and activity. The fragment has a `TextView`, by passing parameters to the Fragment, I want to display different text inside each `TextView` of the Fragments. With this method, I can save creating 139 identical fragments with different texts.

**Problem**, all 8 fragment's `TextView` changes when I `setText()`, because they all share the same template (xml and activity).

**Solution** - see my answer below.

**Extremis**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've learned that something was wrong in my code when I tried to duplicate fragments in th way attempted above.

**My Solution**

I created a new dummy Android project and selected the Navigation type as **Scrollable Tabs + Swipe**.

I then learned that it had 1 activity:

main.java - whcih extends:

`FragmentActivity`

and, 2 layout's:

**main.xml** - which contained:

`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>` , and

`<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>`

**Fragment.xml** - which contained:

`TextView`

By adjusting the adapter, I was able to create unique Fragments based on the Same layout (xml).

So ultimately - Create a new dummy project with the Scrollable Tabs + Swipe and adjust your code based on that example.

Hope this help.

**Extremis**

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you duplicate your Fragment, you refer to the same view for each fragment you create. You have to change the id of the fragment. If you don't do that you call the same fragment all the time.

Final Answer : On onCreateView method

```
private static int id = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle      savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
    mTexTView.setId(Id); 
    id++;
    mLinearLayout.addView(mTextView);

    return mLinearLayout;
}
```

After you can use the id of your textview and set the text.

Comment: Please see Edit 2 above :)

Comment: can you modify my code and post? What do I inflate? Im new to this. Sorry :)

Comment: Thank you, one last question: What do I do inside the onCreateView? what do I return?

Comment: Inside onCreateView you create your view :). You can find the reference here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)

Comment: when I add the `setContentView`, I get the error `this method is undefined for Fragment. Create method?`

Comment: My mistake, time to go to bed. You can't use setContentView for a fragment you need to return a view from onCreateView.

Comment: It works, but the text is still the same for all the fragments :(

Comment: you know the `mTextView.setId("Id")` shouldn't it be `mTextView.setId(id)`

Comment: I've done it and it runs, but the text still changes in all the Fragments :(, could this be because of the FragmentAdapter? something in there?